# Possible cause for piston melt in CNG 6 cylinder?

Tags: engine

1. I don't have engine overheat complaint.
2. There was sufficient engine oil and coolant.
3. Oil pressure also at specified rate?
4. Always I am having this issue on first cylinder at maximum time?

Comment: Please don't shout...

Answer (score 10):

Possibly an air leak on the inlet manifold gasket next to cylinder 1.  Under heavy load, the extra air can cause the fuel to burn hot, which will cause the piston to melt.